# Screen not rendering on startup in Ubuntu 20

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics

I have been using Ubuntu 18 on ASUS ROG for close to an year and it used to work without any incident. Few weeks back, upgraded to Ubuntu 20 and been having some issues. The screen has frozen while using for couple of times now, had to force reboot. Now recently, only top part of screen is being rendered on startup. While it took some time and loaded previously, it has not corrected today, attached an image for reference.

Any help in identifying the issue and any potential solutions would be appreciated.
I don’t have the full hardware info currently but it has an intel i9, 4gb gtx 1650 ti card, 1tb ssd.
Nvidia has been properly configured-GPU programs, steam games etc work fine.

Image-https://imgur.com/a/AwoQCAf

Comment: Specify the exact ubuntu version. i.e. 20.04, 20.10? (your screenshot image is not visible or a link FYI)

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20 are designed for *headless* operation, the *year* format being used only for specialist releases of Ubuntu for use on appliances, devices or cloud use.  The *year* format is used for different products to the far more common *year.month* used by both larger server & desktop releases; such as what you tagged (but didn't mention in your question).